# Xamarin WebView Not loading stream which comes from webrtc

Tags: forms, xamarin

```
class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
  Activity mContext;
  public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
  {
     this.mContext = context as Activity;
  }

  protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
  {
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    Control.ClearCache(true);
    Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
    Control.Settings.PluginsEnabled = true;
    Control.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
    Control.Settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.NoCache;
    Control.Settings.SetRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.High);
    Control.Settings.LightTouchEnabled = true;
    Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebClient(mContext));
    Control.SetWebViewClient(new SSLTolerentWebViewClient());

    Control.LoadUrl(Control.Url);
  }

  public class MyWebClient : WebChromeClient
  {
    Activity mContext;
    public MyWebClient(Activity context)
    {
         this.mContext = context;
    }

    [TargetApi(Value = 21)]
    public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
    {
        mContext.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
          request.Grant(request.GetResources());
        });

     }
 }
    private class SSLTolerentWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {

      public override void OnReceivedSslError(Android.Webkit.WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
      {
          handler.Proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
      }

      public override void OnLoadResource(Android.Webkit.WebView view,string url)
      {

      }
     }
}
```

Comment: Where is your stream loaded in webview exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android doesn't support WebRTC on its native webview yet, as you can see in the official documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

It's not your code. You would have to find a way around it.

Comment: Finally I got it .WebRTC Supports in Xamarin Android Webview.

Comment: How did you resolve it? I was looking into it myself, how did you get WebRTC on your webview?

Comment: give permission camera ,microphone and add this line  Control.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false; in onelementchanged in the  above code

Comment: You should mark that as an answer, so other people looking can try to find it!